# using factory in angularjs getting Error: [$injector:undef]

Tags: angularjs, factory, angular-services

I am creating a new angular App and using factory but when i am am getting an error which is

Error: [$injector:undef] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/undef?p0=Data
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:6:416
    at Object.$get (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:37:32)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:39:96)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:40:410
    at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:38:308)
    at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:39:64)
    at Object.g.instantiate (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:39:213)
    at b.$get (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:80:257)
    at s (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js:12:165)

```
    var app = angular.module('testapp', ['ngRoute']);
        app.config(['$routeProvider',
          function ($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.
                when('/userlist', {
                    title: 'List of all the users',
                    templateUrl: 'userlist.html',
                    controller: 'listuser'
                })
                .when('/profile',{
                    title:'user detail page',
                    templateUrl:'profile.html',
                    controller:'listuser'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/userlist'
                });
        }])

        app.factory("Data", ['$http','$log',
        function ($http,$log) {
            var obj = {};

            obj.post = function (q, object) {
                return $http({
                     method: 'POST',
                     url:'userdetail.php',

                     data: object.user

                })
                .then(function (results) {
                    $log.log(results);
                    return results.data;
                });

            };
        }]);

        app.controller('listuser',['Data', function ($scope,$http,$log,$window,Data) {
            $scope.userdetail = {};
            var init = function () {
            $http({
                     method: 'POST',
                     url: 'apisource.php',

                })
                .then(function (results) {

                    $scope.data=results.data;

                });
            };
            init();
             $scope.douserdetail = function(user) {
                Data.post({
                    user: user
                }).then(function (results) {

                if (results.status == "success") {
                    //$location.path('dashboard');
                }
                });
            };

        }]);
```

Comment: Try to return `obj` object in your factory

Comment: @DomasMar now it say's 

TypeError: $http is not a function
    at init (app.js:44)
    at new <anonymous> (app.js:55)
    at e (angular.js:4473)
    at Object.g.instantiate (angular.js:4481)
    at b.$get (angular.js:9108)
    at s (angular-route.min.js:12)
    at m.a.$get.m.$broadcast (angular.js:16200)
    at angular-route.min.js:9
    at angular.js:14634
    at m.a.$get.m.$eval (angular.js:15878)

Comment: Ah.. yes. Look at your controller. You forgot to inject `$scope, $http, $log, $window` dependencies

Comment: @DomasMar should i need to inject all the dependencies which is in controller ?

Comment: Seeing your other questions asked in the past few weeks I cannot help but see you miss the basics. You make the same errors in your other questions and apparently didn't learn from the answers given. I think the best advice here is to follow some basic introductions to angularjs and try to understand the concepts ( don't just copy the code).

Comment: @DomasMar I am learning my self and i followed your suggestion and understand how angular services worked and i fixed them my self now i have a conceptual issue .I am making a http request initially and then calling a service function .But my problem is when i am calling the service function (as they are in the same controller ) it get called but after that it call initial function also .and my data didn't get updated .Please help me .Much appreciated as i am very beginner and eager to learn .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Factory functions in angular are expected to return an object, but your `"Data"` factory does not return anything. Simply add the following at the end of your factory function to fix the issue:

```
return obj;
```

Comment: now it say's TypeError: $http is not a function
    at init (app.js:44)
    at new <anonymous> (app.js:55)
    at e (angular.js:4473)
    at Object.g.instantiate (angular.js:4481)
    at b.$get (angular.js:9108)
    at s (angular-route.min.js:12)
    at m.a.$get.m.$broadcast (angular.js:16200)
    at angular-route.min.js:9
    at angular.js:14634
    at m.a.$get.m.$eval (angular.js:15878)

Comment: That's a different error. You need to correctly specify the list of dependencies of your `'listuser'` controller (you only define dependency on the "Data" service). Like this:
`app.controller('listuser', ['$scope', '$http', ..., 'Data', function ($scope,$http,$log,$window,Data) { ...` ||| You basically need to tell angular to inject `$http` (and other services) into your controller in the first place. ;)

Comment: I am learning my self and i followed your suggestion and understand how angular services worked and i fixed them my self now i have a conceptual issue .I am making a http request initially and then calling a service function .But my problem is when i am calling the service function (as they are in the same controller ) it get called but after that it call initial function also .and my data didn't get updated .Please help me .Much appreciated as i am very beginner and eager to learn .

Comment: @GauravkumarMVCExpert Just in case you are not familiar with how StackOverflow works - it is not a forum, it's a questions and answers site. If you have a new issue, please open a new question, we cannot solve all of them through a discussion in comments. Also, don't forget to upvote/accept answers that you find useful, it helps with rating the answers for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [link](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/undef?p0=Data) provided in your stacktrace. Your factory has to return a value:

```
app.factory("Data", ['$http','$log',
  function ($http,$log) {
    var obj = {};
    ...
    return obj;
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many error, in controller your are using $http, what is the purpose

You are calling init() inside  the init which will cause the infinite loop

You service is not returning anything

I will suggest to check the basics angular first